# Change image if source contains

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a list that looks like,

```
<li class="">
  <ul class="item  highlightShoplift">
    <li class="title left">
      <img width="30" height="30" src="/images/crimes/c.png?v=1486475443550">
    </li>
    <li class="radio right has-pretty-child">
      <div class="clearfix prettyradio labelright  blue" role="radio" aria-checked="false" aria-disabled="false" "=" ">
        <input type="radio" value="shoplift " name="crime " style="display: none; ">
        <a href="# " role="presentation " tabindex="0 " class=" "></a>
        <label for="undefined " class=" "></label>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="bonus left ">
      Shoplift
    </li>
    <li class="points left ">
      <span class="desc ">-4 Nerve</span>
    </li>
    <li class="clear "></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

and I need to change the image. I need to change it from /images/crimes/c.png to http://medictests.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/checkmark.png

however I'm not sure how. Using jquery/javascript.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on *many things*, for example, *what triggers the change*, *what is the requirement at hand*, etc.

Here is a sample snippet to change the image for a *sample* requirement, say,  *Change the image after a predefined time* using `JavaScript`.

Now that we can accomplish it using plain Vanilla `JavaScript`, here could be the steps:

- Find the Image element that we are aiming at (think about using specific selectors and combinators)
- Understand the timeout period
- Change the `src` attribute of the image to point to the new image

```js
window.onload = function() {
  // Get the Image element
  var img = document.querySelector("ul.item img");

  // New image
  var imageUrl = 'http://medictests.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/checkmark.png';

  // Change the image after a set time, for example
  setTimeout(function() {
    img.setAttribute("src", imageUrl);
  }, 1000);

}
```

```html
<ul class="item  highlightShoplift">
  <li class="title left">
    <img width="30" height="30" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/bf/Bucephala-albeola-010.jpg">
  </li>
</ul>
```

---

Let's go a step further and say - we should replace the image only if the `src` attribute contains a specific term, say, *flower*.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  // Get the Image element
  var imgElements = document.querySelectorAll("ul.item img");

  // New image
  var imageUrl = 'http://medictests.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/checkmark.png';

  imgElements.forEach(function(element, index, array) {

    if (element.src.toLowerCase().includes("flower")) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        element.setAttribute("src", imageUrl);
      }, 1000);
    }
  });

}
```

```html
<ul class="item  highlightShoplift">
  <li class="title left">
    <img width="30" height="30" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/bf/Bucephala-albeola-010.jpg">
  </li>

  <li class="title left">
    <img width="30" height="30" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/0c/White_and_yellow_flower.JPG">
  </li>

  <li class="title left">
    <img width="30" height="30" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a5/Flower_poster_2.jpg">
  </li>


</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add an `id` attribute to the image tag like

```
<img id="imgToChange" width="30" height="30" src="/images/crimes/c.png?v=1486475443550">
```

Then, you can directly change the image `src` attribute like

```
document.getElementById("imgToChange").src= "http://medictests.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/checkmark.png";
```

and Using **jquery**

```
$("#imgToChange").attr('src', 'http://medictests.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/checkmark.png');
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery :

```
$("img").attr('src' ,'http://medictests.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/checkmark.png');
```

Note that is better to give the img a class and target only that particular image.

Answer (score 0):

This is really a bad question, however I think that you need to change an image if its SRC contains a certain word.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function () {
    var src = ''; //YOUR SRC IF STRING CONTAINS
    var other_src = ''; //YOUR SRC IF STRING DOESN'T CONTAIN
    if(src.indexOf('YOUR WORD') > 0) {
        document.getElementById("image").src = src; 
    } else {
        document.getElementById("image").src = other_src; 
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<li class="">
  <ul class="item  highlightShoplift">
    <li class="title left">
      <img width="30" height="30" src="" id="image">
    </li>
    <li class="radio right has-pretty-child">
      <div class="clearfix prettyradio labelright  blue" role="radio" aria-checked="false" aria-disabled="false" "=" ">
        <input type="radio" value="shoplift " name="crime " style="display: none; ">
        <a href="# " role="presentation " tabindex="0 " class=" "></a>
        <label for="undefined " class=" "></label>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="bonus left ">
      Shoplift
    </li>
    <li class="points left ">
      <span class="desc ">-4 Nerve</span>
    </li>
    <li class="clear "></li>
  </ul>
</li>
</body>
</html>
```

Anyway I don't know if this is what you're looking for.